# python: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am following a Youtube tutorial on a streamlit application, however the error

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'"

occured when I was trying to group my list that I scraped from wikipedia, the instructor had the exact code as me but didn't face a problem, where am I missing out exactly?

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd    
@st.cache
    def load_data():
        url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies'
        html = pd.read_html(url, header = 0)
        df = html[0]
        return df
    
    df = load_data()
    df = df.groupby('GICS Sector')
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, I just had to reassign the df variable to it's first index

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

@st.cache
def load_data():
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
    html = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
    df = html[0]
    return df

df = load_data()
df = df[0]
df = df.groupby("GICS Sector")
```